# How do I ensure monit starts on system startup?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monit

I am using the Amazon Linux AMI. I want to ensure that monit on system startup always calls

```
monit -c $CONFIG
```

where `$CONIFG` is the default monit configuration file location (usually `/etc/monit.conf`). I want to ensure it is always monitoring my services on startup.

How do I do this? I'd rather not use `upstart` because I'd like to restrict the number of tools I'm using for this setup.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi check out this [documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html)

It describes how to run programs on startup on CentOS systems (which is what Amazon Linux is). Basically you want to do this

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

then add your command to the bottom of it.